# Unity game cannot be played

Tags: unity-game-engine

I tried sharing a unity game file in an .exe. When I downloaded the file, it said you need to install Unityplayer.dll. What is unityplayer.dll and how do I download it or is there something else I need to do.

Comment: Usually there should be a folder right next to the `.exe` file you have to share along since it contains all needed `.ddl`s and resources

Comment: The exe doesn't actually contain anything. Its just a small wrapper that looks for the `_Data` folder and loads it. I'm also reasonably sure you could even substitute in a completely different build's exe, and as long as the folder is named right (`Xyz_Data` or just `Data`), it'll load up just fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you build your game, it provides you with multiple files. One of it is `Unityplayer.dll`.

If you want to share your built games to somebody else, you need to make sure that you share to them all the files that UnityEditor had built.

More about the missing DLL stuff [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1425830/the-program-cant-start-because-unityplayerdll-is-m.html).